# NestJS blocking new requests after throwing error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, error-handling, nestjs

I've got a small testing application (a test lab) with an `AppControler` and an `AppService`, `AppController` has a `GET` endpoint and send requests payload to `AppService`, which has two async methods.

**AppService**

```js
async requestTesting (payload): Promise<void> { // This is what's being called from the controller
    
  if(payload) {
      await this.validateErrorHandling(payload)
  }

  console.log('TESTING', payload)

// DO STUFF

}

async validateErrorHandling(payload): Promise<void> {
     console.log('DO STUFF')

  if(payload && payload.number > 2) { // This is true
     throw new Error()
  }

}
```

When requestTesting calls validateErrorHandling, the second method is going to check that condition (if truthy) and shall throw an Error.
I'm used to do this with an exception filter on real use cases, but in this very specific case, whenever I call my Controller's endpoint and that error is thrown on my `AppService`, the following is shown:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "........".
```

And I'm unable to make any other request through postman until I restart the app.
Postman shows:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
```

Now, I'm aware that a try/catch should fix this, but I'm trying to understand why this is stopping my whole application instead of stopping the function execution only, as it never happened to me before, and if I try to throw it anywhere else, it just works.

Now, both methods have a `Promise<void>` return type, but if validateErrorHandling throws an error,  everything should stop and that `console.log('TESTING', payload)` should not be executed (as if it were business logic).
I'm afraid it's not just me being silly, but I might actually be missing something.

Comment: you problably forgot some `await`, leaving floating promises around. Check out all promises that are in-place when your controller's method get called

Comment: That's the part that's getting me, I omitted method names and other logic testing (only with console.log() inside of them), but everything is working just fine.

Also, if I throw an error inside the controller, it won't stop the whole application, and altough that should just indicate that I am indeed missing something, I didn't find anything out of the ordinary

Comment: Can you show the controller function too please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that we throw an error is that we want to tell the front application that something went wrong. In order to achieve this, it's better to throw an HTTP error instead of simply throwing it. So here is the code:

```
throw new UnprocessableEntityException({
  errorCode: UpdateProductErrorStatusEnum.DeviceNotReported,
  message: UpdateProductErrorMsgEnum.DeviceNotReported,
});
```

You have two options. First throw the error in the service itself, second to throw an Error (as you did) and catch it in the controller layer. Each way has its own pros and cons. Throwing in the controller is better because the controller is designed to handle HTTP related stuff, and service is created for only logic stuff. But throwing in the controller makes the controller messy and maybe your code will not be clean.

See here for more info: https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that did not answer my question. I'm used to handling errors on NestJS with a customized exception filter library that I made based of Nest global exception filter.

NestJS is blocking (or stopping) the application after an error is thrown on that very specific case , and that's very weird. But thank you, anyway!

Edit: Also, I don't agree with that errors being thrown to "tell the front application that something went wrong" only, it might be used for backend only application as well

Comment: Your exception filter (if it's the same thing that nestjs brings) will catch only HTTP exceptions. So, when you `throw Error()` you should catch it manually. And about your last sentence, yes throwing an error is used in the backend too. For example, you have a module that you publish on npm, then for example, if you do something wrong, the package throws an error (because they want to not let you go further if it's re) and you should handle it properly by catching it.

Comment: So, to sum up, either you throw an error for frontend or backend internal purposes, you should either throw HTTP based errors (for frontend case) or throw and catch it manually (for backend purposes)

Comment: Ah, I had to re-read you answer, I must have been tired and misinterpreted your answer, sorry.
Anyway... What if I need to throw different errors based on business logic? I might create a custom filter that catches every kind of error (that's what the filter I mentioned does), and that would make my controller clean again, right? But if for some reason I don't want to catch errors on my controller?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "Throw in the service" and "Throw an Error and catch it on the controller"? I am throwing it on the service.